# swift calling functions passing vales I'm confused

Tags: function, swift

I'm getting bit confused 
hopefully somebody can put me straight

i have function 
which works as i would expect in the playground

```
    func testFunction(Astring:String,Anumber:Int,Afloat:CGFloat)
{
    println(Astring)
    println(Anumber)
    println(Afloat)   
}

 testFunction("Hello",25,25.00)
```

but in a project i have to call it like this, if i don't i get error missing argument label "Afloat:" in call

```
  testFunction("Hello",Anumber:25,Afloat:25.00)
```

the only difference is I'm calling the function from a button?
thanks for the help of this site without it I would be lost

Comment: I think this will answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24046893/3207979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, parameters after the first parameter require you to use the external name.  If you do not want an external name, then you have to define that in the function.  Also as a style point, local variables should start with lower case.  Regardless, this should get you what you want.  The "_" character basically says no external name.

```
func testFunction(aString:String, _ aNumber:Int, _ aFloat:CGFloat)
```

Comment: hi thanks I've learnt something today cheers i like  to call functions without external names keeps the code cleaner thanks for the style point I'm pretty bad at writing in general so my code is quite messy