# swift inner,outter function parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I declared a function, for example,

> func test(a: Int, b: Int)

but when I invoke it, i have to put a code like this:

> test(12, b: 32)

It looks so weird !

I declared the **test** function with symmetrical parameters, but the function call is not symmetric.

How can I declare the function to make the function call exactly like this:

> test(12, 32)

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045890/why-does-a-function-call-require-the-parameter-name-in-swift .

Comment: Have a look at ["Function Parameter Names"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) in the Swift book ... it is all documented.

Comment: imyogish, Martin R thx, both of u! I seems the # has been canceled in swift2! I get it thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full form of function declarations is:

```
func test(parameterLabelA parameterNameA: Type, parameterLabelB parameterNameB: Type)
```

By default if you omit labels as in:

```
func test(a: Int, b: Int)
```

the following form is inferred:

```
func test(_ a: Int, b b: Int)
```

where _ means no label.

In order to remove the b label you can declare your function as:

```
func test(a: Int, _ b: Int)
```

Note however that this is not the recommended style.

Comment: like Nicholas points out, it is not the recommended style, it could lead to confusion. Just rather use:
func( test test : Int, test2 test2 : Int)

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
func test(x : Int, _ y : Int) {
    print(x)
    print(y)
}
```

Edit: added inner parameter names.

Comment: How do you access the values of the parameters in the body of the function in this form?