# Swift: difference between function calling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am novice in Swift programming. I am not able to understand following code. In following code to call

1. **incrementBy** method: I must have to type **numberOfTimes** in second argument. But,
2. **sampleFunc** method: I must not have to type **lastName** in second argument.

   ```
   class Counter {
   var count: Int = 0
   func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes : Int) {
       count += amount * numberOfTimes
   }
   }

   var counter = Counter()
   counter.incrementBy(1, numberOfTimes : 3)
   print(counter.count)

   func sampleFunc(firstName : String, lastName : String){
   print("Hello \(firstName) \(lastName)")
   }

   sampleFunc("Abel", "Rosnoski")
   ```

Why is there subtle difference? Please explain.

Comment: You want lastName in sampleFunc as optional value, right?

Comment: No I think he is asking that when you have to use "Named parameter" and when you can make do without the named parameter by just giving the value. Is that right @umangKothari?

Comment: It gives error as "Missed argument lastName" when compile like this `sampleFunc("Abel", "Rosnoski")` So, you need to use your second argument name like this `sampleFunc("Abel", lastName: "Rosnoski")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a function call require the parameter name in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045890/why-does-a-function-call-require-the-parameter-name-in-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When encapsulated in a class (or struct or enum), the first parameter name of a method is not included externally, while all following parameter names are included externally. The parameters which are not included externally, you don't have to give names for them when calling the method. But for externally included ones you have to.

Your method `incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes : Int)` is encapsulated in your class that's why the second parameter is automatically externally included. Which means you have to type `numberOfTimes` before providing value to parameter. That's why you must call it like:

```
counter.incrementBy(1, numberOfTimes : 3)
```

Your second method `func sampleFunc(firstName : String, lastName : String)` is not enclosed in your class. That's why you don't have to provide name for its parameters. Which is why you can call it like:

```
sampleFunc("Abel", "Rosnoski")
```

You can read more details [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/swift-functions/).

Edit: As User3441734 kindly pointed out (And I quote) "There is one exception. init with parameters always requires named parameter, if the external name is not specified as _ ". You can read more about [Customizing initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_295) here.

Comment: there is one exception. init with parameters always requires named parameter, if the external name is not specified as _

Answer (score 4):

@NSNoob made a nice explanation, I just added some examples to understand power of function calls:

```
func sampleFunc(firstName : String, lastName : String) {}
sampleFunc("First", lastName: "Last")
```

You can remove naming second param like this:

```
func sampleFunc(firstName : String, _ lastName : String) {}
sampleFunc("First", "Last")
```

If you want to add naming for all params:

```
func sampleFunc(firstName firstName : String, lastName : String) {}
sampleFunc(firstName: "First", lastName: "Last")
```

If you want to make default value for param:

```
func sampleFunc(firstName firstName : String, lastName : String = "Last") {}
sampleFunc(firstName: "First")
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is not remotely explaining the concept of externally included parameters or the effect of a method being enclosed in the class.  You are simply assuming that method is outside the class.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote already, that you explained well. It's not necessary to write the one thing twice. I just added some value information

Comment: Also I would like to note that in the signature `func sampleFunc(firstName firstName : String, lastName : String)`  the external and internal parameter name `firstName` is same so you don't have to type it twice. Just put a # before it. Something like this: 
`func sampleFunc(#firstName : String, lastName : String)`

Comment: # has been removed from Swift. it doesn't compile in `Swift 2.1`

Answer (score 0):

```
func a(param1:Double, param2:Double) -> Double {
    return param1*param2;
}

func a2(p1 param1:Double,p2 param2:Double) -> Double {
    return param1*param2;
}
```

As I understood and done some trials in playground, you have to use the parameter names if you don't define argument labels.

```
var c = a(3.2,2.3)
c //gives error

var b = a(param1:3.2,param2:2.3);
b

var d = a2(p1:3.2,p2:2.3);
d

var e = a2(param1:3.2,param2:2.3)
e //gives error
```