# Function with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift, actually I started learning it today. Can someone tell me whats wrong with calling the function in this way?

```
func myAddition(i:NSInteger,j:NSInteger) ->NSInteger {
    i
    j
    return i+j
}

myAddition(5, 6)
```

**Edit**
I fixed the error by inserting j:

```
myAddition(5, j: 6)
```

is this normal? I am following a tutorial and there its working without j

Comment: You don't need `NSInteger` for such simple operations. Use an `Int` instead.

Comment: What are i and j doing on lines 2 and 3?

Comment: are you getting error while calling this? if yes then what is it?

Comment: [Swift Programming Series (iBooks Store)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book-series/swift-programming-series/id888896989?mt=11)

Comment: @vacawama They're probably using a Playground. Doing this displays the variable values in the side panel.

Comment: I changed it to Int, still the same problem.
@vacawama I am using a Playgroun, I wanted to see the value of i and j

Comment: @EricD, thanks.  I use Playgrounds all the time, but I guess my *old school* mindset prevented me from seeing the use of variables that are accessed but "not used".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to call the function without specifying the parameter names, then you have to tell Swift that there are no external parameter names for the function by using the underbar (_) as the external parameter name:

```
func myAddition(_ i:NSInteger, _ j:NSInteger) -> NSInteger {
    return i+j
}

myAddition(5, 6)
```

Do you really need an NSInteger as opposed to a normal Swift Int:

```
func myAddition(_ i:Int , _ j:Int) -> Int {
    return i+j
}

myAddition(5, 6)
```

Comment: I think the need to specify the first parameter name on the function call has changed between different versions of Swift , which is why you might not be seeing the same results as the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call method in this way:

```
 myAddition(5, j: 6)
```

Try this it may help you.

Comment: Thank you it works but can you explain me why? In the tutorial its working without the j:

Comment: @User1932 Visit this link it will help you to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045890/why-does-a-function-call-require-the-parameter-name-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

```
func myAddition(i:Int,j:Int) ->Int {
    return i+j
}

print(myAddition(5, j: 6))
```

This will work for you.